# Dummy variable for diff in diff

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am using difference in difference for my data. Now while calculating it manually, I am able to find the dif in dif and the code works but when I am trying to perform regression, its not happening. It is because there is some problem with the dummy variable. If any of you can help, it would be really great.

```
> setwd("C:\\Users\\Rahul Shukla\\Desktop\\Replicationdata\\data")
> assessment<- read.csv("..\\data\\assessment3.csv")
> str(assessment)
'data.frame':   29392 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ ï..year         : int  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
 $ disecode        : chr  "8040100201" "8040100201" "8040100201" "8040100201" ...
 $ class           : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ student_id      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ gender          : chr  "B" "B" "G" "B" ...
 $ lang_pa         : chr  "P" "P" "P" "P" ...
 $ lang_total      : num  6.25 0 0 1.5 7.5 ...
 $ lang_percentage : num  19.5 0 0 4.7 23.4 25.8 15.6 0 35.2 0 ...
 $ maths_pa        : chr  "P" "P" "P" "P" ...
 $ maths_total     : int  9 5 4 8 3 5 7 6 4 7 ...
 $ maths_percentage: num  34.6 19.2 15.4 30.8 11.5 19.2 26.9 23.1 15.4 26.9 ...
 $ prepost         : chr  "bl" "bl" "bl" "bl" ...
 $ treatment       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> post_treatment_data<- assessment[assessment$ï..year>=2017,]
> simpleols<- lm(post_treatment_data$lang_percentage~post_treatment_data$treatment)
> summary(simpleols)

Call:
lm(formula = post_treatment_data$lang_percentage ~ post_treatment_data$treatment)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-39.346 -13.746  -0.746  14.310  69.210 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    27.6904     0.2942   94.12   <2e-16 ***
post_treatment_data$treatment  11.6555     0.3541   32.91   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 20.66 on 15911 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06374,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.06368 
F-statistic:  1083 on 1 and 15911 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> simpleols2<- lm(post_treatment_data$maths_percentage~post_treatment_data$treatment)
> summary(simpleols2)

Call:
lm(formula = post_treatment_data$maths_percentage ~ post_treatment_data$treatment)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-38.74 -13.04  -2.04  12.09  68.79 

Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    27.9073     0.2877   97.00   <2e-16 ***
post_treatment_data$treatment  10.8327     0.3463   31.28   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 20.2 on 15911 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05793,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.05787 
F-statistic: 978.3 on 1 and 15911 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> control_lan_pretreatment <- mean(assessment$lang_percentage[assessment$treatment==0 & assessment$ï..year>=2016])
> control_lan_posttreatment <- mean(assessment$lang_percentage[assessment$treatment==0 & assessment$ï..year<=2017])
> treated_lan_pretreatment <- mean(assessment$lang_percentage[assessment$treatment==1 & assessment$ï..year>=2016])
> treated_lan_posttreatment <- mean(assessment$lang_percentage[assessment$treatment==1 & assessment$ï..year<=2017])
> parallel_trends <- (treated_lan_posttreatment - control_lan_posttreatment) - (treated_lan_pretreatment - control_lan_pretreatment) 
> parallel_trends
[1] 6.734934
> selection_bias <- (treated_lan_posttreatment - treated_lan_pretreatment) - (control_lan_posttreatment - control_lan_pretreatment)
> selection_bias
[1] 6.734934
> control_math_pretreatment <- mean(assessment$maths_percentage[assessment$treatment==0 & assessment$ï..year>=2016])
> control_math_posttreatment <- mean(assessment$maths_percentage[assessment$treatment==0 & assessment$ï..year<=2017])
> treated_math_pretreatment <- mean(assessment$maths_percentage[assessment$treatment==1 & assessment$ï..year>=2016])
> treated_math_posttreatment <- mean(assessment$maths_percentage[assessment$treatment==1 & assessment$ï..year<=2017])
> parallel_trends <- (treated_math_posttreatment - control_math_posttreatment) - (treated_math_pretreatment - control_math_pretreatment) 
> parallel_trends
[1] 5.649621
> selection_bias <- (treated_math_posttreatment - treated_math_pretreatment) - (control_math_posttreatment - control_math_pretreatment)
> selection_bias
[1] 5.649621
> dput(head(assessment, 25))
structure(list(ï..year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L), disecode = c("8040100201", "8040100201", "8040100201", 
"8040100201", "8040100201", "8040100201", "8040100201", "8040100201", 
"8040100201", "8040100201", "8040100201", "8040100201", "8040100201", 
"8040100201", "8040100201", "8040101302", "8040101302", "8040101302", 
"8040101302", "8040101302", "8040101302", "8040103002", "8040103002", 
"8040103002", "8040103002"), class = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), student_id = 1:25, gender = c("B", "B", "G", "B", 
"G", "G", "B", "G", "G", "B", "G", "B", "G", "B", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "B", "B"), lang_pa = c("P", "P", 
"P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", 
"P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P"), lang_total = c(6.25, 
0, 0, 1.5, 7.5, 8.25, 5, 0, 11.25, 0, 0, 0, 8.5, 9, 0, 6, 21.5, 
4.5, 14, 10, 18, 7.5, 1, 9.5, 8.5), lang_percentage = c(19.5, 
0, 0, 4.7, 23.4, 25.8, 15.6, 0, 35.2, 0, 0, 0, 26.6, 28.1, 0, 
18.8, 67.2, 14.1, 43.8, 31.3, 56.3, 23.4, 3.1, 29.7, 26.6), maths_pa = c("P", 
"P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", 
"P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P"), maths_total = c(9L, 
5L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 
12L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 0L, 10L, 12L), maths_percentage = c(34.6, 
19.2, 15.4, 30.8, 11.5, 19.2, 26.9, 23.1, 15.4, 26.9, 26.9, 23.1, 
23.1, 42.3, 3.8, 0, 46.2, 34.6, 23.1, 26.9, 50, 34.6, 0, 38.5, 
46.2), prepost = c("bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl"), treatment = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
> ##Creating a dummy variable
> assessment$post_treatment <- ifelse (assessment$ï..year>=2017,1,0)
> assessment$post_treatment_treated <- ifelse(assessment$treatment==1 & assessment$ï..year>=2017,1,0)
> interaction_model<- lm(lang_percentage~post_treatment_treated+post_treatment+post_treatment_treated*post_treatment,data=assessment)
> summary((interaction_model))

Call:
lm(formula = lang_percentage ~ post_treatment_treated + post_treatment + 
    post_treatment_treated * post_treatment, data = assessment)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-39.346 -13.390  -0.529  12.054  72.871 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                            22.7289     0.1620  140.28   <2e-16 ***
post_treatment_treated                 11.6555     0.3225   36.15   <2e-16 ***
post_treatment                          4.9614     0.3131   15.85   <2e-16 ***
post_treatment_treated:post_treatment       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 18.81 on 29389 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1403,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1402 
F-statistic:  2397 on 2 and 29389 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: You should provide some sample data using `dput`. You also need to provide the actual error message(s) and indicate where in the code they appear.

Comment: how can I do that? can you provide me your email. I can share the code and data

Comment: Use `dput(head(assessment, 25))` and paste the results into a code block so it looks like the one I created for your code. Run that sample and see if it generates the error.

Comment: Sir, I am completely new into this. I am still figuring out things. So I am not understanding. I can share with the dataset but I don't see any link to provide the dataset here.

Comment: I am trying to paste the results

Comment: I have pasted the results. Please have a look.

Comment: Your sample breaks on the second line. Run your code before you post it. Give us the text of the error message ("it's not happening" is not informative) and tell us where in your code that occurs.

Comment: Hi SIr, I have ran the codes and pasted the results. Now you must have been able to see the NA NA NA NA value in the regression results.

Comment: Here is the problem - "Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)".  The interaction between post_treatment_treated and post_treatment is the problem. Look at `xtabs(~post_treatment_treated+post_treatment, assessment)`. Probably one of the cells of the table is 0.

Comment: Thanks, sir. The problem got solved.